# Не отображается ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, android-fragment

Небольшой ScrollView, который при билде не отображается на устройстве. Фатальных ошибок нет, поэтому я не пойму, что делаю не так.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="25dp"
            android:paddingRight="25dp">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:textSize="16sp"

                android:theme="@style/customSpinner"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.044"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="25dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/elements_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center|left"
                        android:text="@string/example_title"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorHeader"
                        app:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
                        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                        android:text="@string/example_chapter_title"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorHeaderHalf"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center|left"
                        android:text="@string/example_title"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorHeader"
                        app:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
                        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                        android:text="@string/example_chapter_title"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorHeaderHalf"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center|left"
                        android:text="@string/example_title"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorHeader"
                        app:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
                        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                        android:text="@string/example_chapter_title"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorHeaderHalf"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

В итоге получается так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Самое странное в том, что Spinner и его LinearLayout отображаются!

**Примечание:** весь код находится в fragment.

Comment: Вы уверены, что ссылки должны содержать `+`? Например, [здесь](https://m.habr.com/ru/company/touchinstinct/blog/326814/) его нет. Ссылки в `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf` и подобном

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов прав, уберите `+` и тогда будет адекватная привязка к виджетам